# cakephp core 3.2.1 composer update

Tags: php, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

After I upgraded cakephp 3.2.1 via composer. I got a list of suggestions. How do I go about install them?

- symfony/console suggests installing symfony/event-dispatcher ()
- symfony/console suggests installing symfony/process ()
- symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-symfony_debug ()
- psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pcntl (Enabling the PCNTL extension
  makes PsySH a lot happier :))
- psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command
  requires SQLite to work.)
- cakephp/debug_kit suggests installing ext-sqlite (DebugKit needs to
  store panel data in a database. SQLite is simple and easy to use.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Symfony bundles you can find on Packagist.org. eg.
https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/event-dispatcher 
the PCNTL extension is a PHP is for process control. I dont think its available on windows yet. you have to download it and compile with a CGI or CLI version of PHP.
If you're running a SQL server i wouldnt worry about the SQLite stuff (personal preference)

Comment: Thanks Nick! What about mySQL?